# Check if an image is a part of a bigger image ( Python )

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have to find if an image is part of a image . The smaller image may be a little scaled horizontally in the bigger image .Is there any way to solve this problem without segmenting the image at specific locations and comparing ?

I tried using cv2.matchTemplate() but since the image may be scaled it didn't work
ex :
find if[symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fzNZ.png) is present in [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4npGX.png)

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l = {}
# objective : to find if a set of symbols is present in a image

def is_template_in_img(img, templ):
    # finding the template in the image
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, templ, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
    max_val = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)[1]
    # thr = 10e-6
    return max_val


# Read template
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg',0)
path = 'symbols'

# find if a symbol is present in a image
for symb_no in range(1,10): 
    # symbol
    symbol = cv2.imread(path+"//"+str(symb_no)+".png",0)
    symbol = cv2.resize(symbol,(symbol.shape[1],int(symbol.shape[0]*img.shape[1]/img.shape[0])))
    # creating a dictionary of template mathcing with the symbol number
    l[symb_no] = is_template_in_img(img,symbol)
    # plt.imshow(img)
# printing the value of each symbol present in the image (to determine the presence of the symbol in image)
print({k: v for k, v in sorted(l.items(), key=lambda item: -item[1])})
```

Comment: Resize the matching image as same as "part of image" then use cv2.matchTemplate()

Comment: check this out:  https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BrijeshVarsani ECC only works if you have a sufficiently close alignment already. matchTemplate does not test multiple scales.

Comment: @istymisty post input data. [mre] requires it.

Comment: I have added a sample input @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: from eyeballing this (didn't look closely), the instance of your template also appears to be squashed a little, compared to the template. -- you'd better show real data. this looks like mockups.